# Finding Prime Numbers using For Loops in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, break

This is my first post here, so I hope I am doing everything correctly.

I have a bit of a problem with my most recent programming challenge.  The goal is to have the user input a number and have the program output all of the prime numbers between 0 and the number entered.  My strategy was to have a for loop run a simple check on every number from 1 to the number entered by dividing it by every preceding number until the loop reached 1.  If at any point in the check, the program encountered a number that divided into the number that the loop is currently on, that section of the loop was to "break" and continue on to the next number.  If the divisor reached 1 then the program would have successfully determined that nothing could divide into the original number evenly and output that number as being prime.

I am very new to programming, but I think it's a problem with how I'm using break.  When the program is compiled, it only prints the original number that was entered and nothing else.  However, I have checked to make sure that all of my integers and loops are working.  Any help regarding my aforementioned problem or if I can make my code more efficient or "correct" would be appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain()
{
    using namespace std;
    int iUserInput;
    cin >> iUserInput;

    for(;iUserInput > 0; iUserInput--)
    {
        int iDivisor = iUserInput - 1;
        for (; iDivisor > 0; iDivisor--)
        {
            if (iUserInput%iDivisor == 0)
                break;
            if (iDivisor == 1)
                cout << iUserInput << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following part:

> ```
> if (iDivisor == 1)
>     cout << iUserInput << endl;
> ```

is at the wrong position. You need to put it *outside* of the inner loop:

```
for(;iUserInput > 0; iUserInput--)
{
    int iDivisor = iUserInput - 1;
    for (; iDivisor > 0; iDivisor--)
    {
        if (iUserInput%iDivisor == 0)
            break;
    }
    if (iDivisor == 1)
        cout << iUserInput << endl;
}
```

Other observations:

- `#include "stdafx.h"` is completely unnecessary here. Remove it.
- `int _tmain()` is not standard. Make it `int main()` and make sure it compiles like this.
- `iUserInput` is Hungarian Notation. Consider it a failed Microsoft experiment from the 90s which is completely useless in modern C++. Call the variable `userInput`.
- Changing the value of the `userInput` variable may hurt readability of the code. After all, the user input does not change after it has been entered. Consider counting down a copy of `userInput`, e.g. `for(int count = userInput; count > 0; count--)`.
- Make your other `for` loop more compact, too: `for (int divisor = userInput - 1; divisor > 0; divisor--)`.
- Perhaps too advanced for someone who really just started learning C++, but you should try to handle illegal user input, e.g. someone entering "X" instead of a number. You can check the state of `std::cin` after each input operation to see if the last operation succeeded or not. Otherwise your program may exhibit undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking too soon :) when iDivisor is 1, iUserInput%iDivisor must equal zero, and the second condition never gets evaluated. Just swap the two if statements and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what order your if conditions are getting executed. When iDivisor reaches 1 you break instead of printing. Either 
1) swap your if conditions or 
2) modify inner loop to terminate when iDivisor reaches 1 and move second if condition outside inner for loop.